# JCrop inconsistent click behavior with and without aspectRatio set

Tags: jcrop

If you set minSize, Jcrop seems to have different click behavior, depending on whether or not you are additionally setting the aspectRatio option. If you set minSize + aspectRatio, you have to **click and drag** to get the crop box to to display; if you set minSize without setting aspectRatio, all you have to do is **click** to get the crop box.

This is easy to reproduce on JCrop's advanced demo page (http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=advanced):

- If you have "Allow new selections" and "minSize/maxSize setting" checked, all you have to do is **click** inside the image to get the crop box to display.
- If you have "Allow new selections," minSize/maxSize setting," and "Aspect ratio" checked, then you have to **click and drag** inside the image to get the crop box to display.

Has anyone had any luck getting the crop box to display with just a **click** in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling the setSelect API method on the click event.  The x and y coordinates are available to you, you just need to specify a width and height.

For example:

```
jcrop_api.setOptions({
  setSelect:    [10,10,100,100],
  aspectRatio:2
});
```

where jcrop_api is initialized when "attaching" jcrop to an image:

```
$j(function($) {
    $('#leftImg').Jcrop({
        onSelect: checkSelection,
        onChange: checkSelection,
        onRelease: wholeImage,
        bgOpacity:0.2,
        bgColor:"white"
        },function(){jcrop_api = this;}
    );
});
```